# PHP fetch_assoc is cutting my String

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code in PHP:

```
$i=0;
$resultado= $_GET['resultado'];
echo "<div class=informacion> <b>Usted busco:</b> $resultado </br></br>";
$consultaNegocios = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM negocios WHERE nombre LIKE '%$resultado%' OR keywords LIKE '%$resultado%'");
$row_cnt = $consultaNegocios->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt != 0) {
    while ($row = $consultaNegocios->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $logo = $row['logo'];
        $title = $row['nombre'];
        $telefono = $row['telefono'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $direccion = $row['direccion'];
        echo '
        <a href=./detalles/'.$title.'><img src='.$logo.' width=100px height=100px align=left alt=logo de '.$title.'>
        <h2> '.$title.' </a> </h2> 

        <p><b>Direccion: </b>'.$direccion.' </br>
        <b>Telefono:</b>'.$telefono.' </br>
        <b>Palabras de busqueda:</b> '.$keywords.' </br></p>
        </div>
        ';
    }
} else{
    echo "<br><br>No hay resultados";
}
```

I have in the query of $title row this in MYSQL: Hello World, but if I do echo $title it returns only Hello, the first word. What can I do to return all the String?

EDIT: All the code UPDATED

Comment: check with your Table Field Title

Comment: show full fragment of your code please :-)

Comment: I want to show ALL the String and NOT the first Word, sorry if I explained wrong

Comment: well, "nombre" seems to mean "number", in Spanish and French, so... what is the column's type and length?

Comment: Nothing in there is going to limit your string length or the amount of words, what is your database field structure?

Comment: No, nombre is name and is Varchar 150 || nombre varchar(150) utf8_spanish_ci Not Null

Comment: Tu nombre es @Fred-ii-

Comment: Have you simplified the problem? Just var_dump the data to see what you get returned. `while( $row = $consultaNegocios->fetch_assoc() ){var_dump($row)};`. You are not quoting your html attributes, so that could look weird when they have spaces.

Comment: Print out this .this will help you in identifying the issue  $row = $consultaNegocios->fetch_assoc();      print_r($row)

Comment: @Devon My Spanish is limited, but my Italian is *molto bene* ;-) my mistake on "nombre" for number, is "name". I stand corrected.

Comment: array(19) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["nombre"]=> string(11) "Hello World" ["categoria"]=> string(14) "Refaccionarias"

Comment: @Fred-ii-, my italian is all from Mario.

Comment: we need to see sample data of what's in your table

Comment: @Sergio, so Hello World isn't cut off.  You do, however, have </a> and </h2> in the wrong order and no quotes around your HTML attributes..

Comment: Yea, looks like the problem is just your html, check you matching tags, and quote the attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="./detalles/'.$title.'"><img src="'.$logo.'" width="100px" height="100px" align="left" alt="logo de '.$title.'" />
        <h2> '.$title.'</h2> </a>
        <p><b>Direccion: </b>'.$direccion.' </br>
        <b>Telefono:</b>'.$telefono.' </br>
        <b>Palabras de busqueda:</b> '.$keywords.' </br></p>
        ';
   }
} else{
    echo "<br><br>No hay resultados";
}
echo '</div>';
```

**Explanation** For those who is interested in:

1. You should better use any concept of templating or MVC to output html page in php.
2. In this particular case OP doesn't respect HTML format:

   ex : `width=100px height=100px` should be `width="100px" height="100px"`

   ex : `<a href=./detalles/'.$title.'>...` should be `<a href="./detalles/'.$title.'">...`

   ex : `<a ...>...<h2> '.$title.' </a> </h2>` should be `<a ...>...<h2> '.$title.' </h2> </a>` or `<a ...>... </a> <h2> '.$title.' </h2>` (not break html structure)
3. `echo '</div>';` close tag was included in loop body when open tag was outside the loop. So to fix html we need to extract it from the loop and put after the loop. Or we can include some open tag `<div>` in the loop. But I think in this case it is not what OP was expecting.

Comment: Yes it works!! It seems that was a HTML problem. Thanks everyone

Comment: Great, now what did you do to make it work? An explanation will also help future readers to the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- hope it will really help anybody, but not sure :-)

Comment: I'm sure it will Alex, believe me ;-)

Comment: The obvious thing was putting quotes around all the HTML attributes.

Comment: @James Obvious for experienced coders, yes. However, for the less experienced people, the added explanation will help to point out where the errors were made. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, hence my comment.  I should rephrase "obvious thing" to "most likely fix"